# The value of the object is not updating immediately in the React state, can any one resolve this issue?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, state

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { faShoppingBasket, faPlusSquare, faLeaf, faMinusSquare, faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import './Banner.css';

const Banner = () => {
const  products = ['Strawberry','Blueberry','Orange','Banana','Apple','Carrot','Celery','Mushroom','Green Pepper','Eggs','Cheese',
'Butter','Chicken','Bread','Pork','Rice','Pasta'];
const [cart,setCart] = useState([]);

const addToCart=(prd)=>{

```
  console.log(prd);
 const exist =  cart.find(product=> product.Name===prd && ++product.Num)
 if(!exist){
  const cartItem={
     Name:prd,
     Num:1
  }
  const newCart = [...cart,cartItem]
  setCart(newCart);
  console.log({cart});
 }
```

}
return (

<div className='mainBanner' style={{height:'250px',background:'#2a2929',color:'white'}}>
<div className='logo' style={{paddingTop:'40px',textAlign:'center'}}>

### Hello, Basket!

#### Groceries

{products.map(prd=>

#### <span onClick={()=>addToCart(prd)}> {prd}

)}

```
     <div className='cart'>
     <div style={{display:'inline'}}><h3 style={{display:'inline'}}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingBasket} size = '2x'/>Basket</h3> 
     <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash} size = '2x'/>
     </div>
      
     {cart.map(prd=> <div className='item'><h3><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusSquare} color='grey'/> {prd.Num}{prd.Name} </h3></div>)}
     </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

);
};

export default Banner;

Comment: State changes are asynchronous. You can't `console.log` them on the very next line and see their new value. Put the `console.log` in the main body of the function to see it's real time value

Comment: dont expect direct update after setXXXX function. these are async functions

Comment: Latest state will appear in rerender phase. Try loging just above where you return jsx. If you are interested to have a deep dive of why state change is asynchronous check this answer by dan abramov https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710

Comment: improve the format and add details explaining your challenge

Answer (score 0):

State changes are asynchronous thus if you will put console.log in the very next line, it won't show updated results. Put console.log outside this addToCart function, You will see the result when the state gets updated.

Comment: i want to render this not into console

Comment: When the state will update, it will automatically render the content inside the cart state

Comment: No  its not woking. this is my code base link:https://github.com/prosourav/basket